# jQuery Selector & Events

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

Jquery UI Function:

```
// Datepicker
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
inline: true
});
```

Event:

```
<input name="txtLogistics_ExecutionDate" type="text" id="datepicker" onfocus="datepicker();" />
```

My question is:

have confusion on how to implement datepicker across multiple text fields.

Do I have to named each text field ID on the function?
How can I assign to any field or pass the ID to Jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a class, for example:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  inline: true
});
```

With elements like this:

```
<input class="datepicker" name="txtLogistics_ExecutionDate" type="text" />
<input class="datepicker" name="txtLogistics_OtherDate" type="text" />
<input class="datepicker" name="txtLogistics_YetAnotherDate" type="text" />
```

This will apply the `.datepicker()` widget to each element with that class.

Comment: @Codex73 - Nope :) just run it on `document.ready`, e.g.: `$(function() { $('.datepicker').datepicker({ inline: true }); });` and it'll execute against all elements once they're in the DOM/ready to go.